# java NullPointerException when I use "Object A" to call a method from "Object B"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm new to Java and my current process is probably over-complicated, but I think there's a lesson here that I need to learn (plus functionality that I need to achieve!)

Basically: I can use my ButtonPanel object to call methods from my MiddlePanelControl object, but neither of them can call an identical method from my GUI object. For the sake of this conversation, I'm just trying to display a System.out.println() string of text. But when I call ANY method from my GUI object, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ButtonPanel$1.actionPerformed(ButtonPanel.java:92)
```

I'm using the ButtonPanel object to call methods. I've initialized the variables for both of those objects within the ButtonPanel constructor, and I refer to them in a similar way.

I start the whole process by creating an object of class: Game. Game creates a GUI object, a ButtonPanel object, and a MiddlePanelControl object, and stores each of them in variables. The three objects refer to the original Game object to access each other. (so, in ButtonPanel I say gui = Game.gui;  and middlePanel = Game.middlePanel). After that I can use ButtonPanel to call middlePanel.anyMethod(); and it works great! But gui.anyMethod(); always gives the nullpointerexception.

Here's the entire Game class:

```
public class Game
{
    public static GUI gui;
    public static MiddlePanelControl middleControl;
public static ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

/**
 * constructor
 */
public Game()
    {
    middleControl = new MiddlePanelControl();
    buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
    gui = new GUI();
    gui.printBull();
}
}
```

Here is where I initialize the variables within the ButtonPanel's constructor:

```
    gui = Game.gui;
    middleControl = Game.middleControl;
```

Here is the offending text from within ButtonPanel code:

```
private void makeButtons()
{
    button01 = new JButton(buttonText01);
    button02 = new JButton(buttonText02);
    button03 = new JButton(buttonText03);
    button04 = new JButton(buttonText04);
    button05 = new JButton(buttonText05);
    button06 = new JButton(buttonText06);

          button01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {gui.printBull();}
    });


    button02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {middleControl.printBull();}
    });

    button03.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {printBull();}
    });
}
```

button01 DOES NOT work.
button02 DOES work.
button03 DOES work.

My problem is that I don't recognize why there is a different relationship for ButtonPanel-GUI than there is for ButtonPanel-MiddlePanelControl. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Where is the `makeButtons` method invoked?

Comment: The best way to solve this would be to use a debugger, since gui could be null, but it could be something else that leads it to be null. If you really don't want to do this then you can print out your variables before invoking methods on them to see if it prints null anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Game` constructor does this:

```
buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
gui = new GUI();
```

The first line calls the `ButtonPanel` constructor, which saves the value of `Game.gui`--**before `gui` has been set up**.  When you're constructing the new `ButtonPanel`, you haven't yet constructed a new `GUI`.

Fixing that will get you going, but overall this is a poor design.  Having a `new Game` set up *static* class fields that other classes use is asking for trouble.  In general, static fields like this are something to be avoided.

Comment: You're saying that the ButtonPanel just saves a null? That makes sense! I will rearrange that and see if it works. Yeah and I also create instances of some of the classes which are also static... I will clean some of that up and rearrange it. Can you tell me: is it bad for me to be saying gui = Game.gui;  ? It seems smart to use Game to different objects refer to the same instances of classes, but that capital Game seems bad somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the code in your `Game` constructor:

```
middleControl = new MiddlePanelControl();
buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
gui = new GUI();
```

First a `MiddlePanelControl` is created, then a `ButtonPanel`, *then* a `GUI`.

The order here is important:  when the `new ButtonPanel()` runs, `middleControl` has been set to an object but `gui` is still null because the program hasn't reached the line that creates the `GUI` yet.

Then, in your `ButtonPanel` constructor, you do

```
gui = Game.gui;
middleControl = Game.middleControl;
```

but `Game.gui` is still null so `ButtonPanel.gui` ends up being null too.  And when this constructor finishes, and the program returns to the `Game` constructor and initializes `Game.gui` with an object, `ButtonPanel.gui` is *still* null.

Comment: I've got some heavy rewriting to do, lol. These classes are way too "tightly coupled" (as the textbook calls it). Thanks!